# Render Image View dynamically as per device screen size

Tags: android, xml, android-imageview

I have been working on setting image view size such that on multiple screen sizes the aspect ratio of image does not get distorted. For that i have used `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` property on image view. But due this property while the images load in image view it takes the whole screen size and when image is downloaded from server its size get proper.

I also tried to change the image view size programmatically according to the screen size and pixel density of phone, but it didn't worked.

The code of image view is as follows:

```html
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/event_image_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.5"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image_not_available"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_image"
    />
```

While images are loading this is how image view's height get equivalent to whole screen:
[image] 
And this is how it get in proper shape when image get downloaded from server.
[image]

Can any one please suggest any way to fix this.

Comment: If you can change API, then best way to do it is get image size (or ratio) and place there any placeholder image.

Comment: I am already using a placeholder image but it seems placeholder image is never visible and image view get in process of getting bitmap from server.

Comment: What is the parent layout? Have you tried modifying or removing `weight` attribute?

Comment: Parent layout is linear layout. Ya, i have tried removing weight attribute but it didn't affected the layout.

Comment: I would say that if there is no change when removing wight, problem must lies in placeholder image itself. Try using smaller one, or even better some custom drawable .xml ... 
Easiest solution would be to use fixed height, but obviously this has its own problems.